# result difference between MySql Query and asp.net c#

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I have a MySql command like below:

```
    string listfh = "Select class_id, location_nm, b.ref_desc, c.ref_desc ,a.days From fh_info as a LEFT JOIN (ref_section as b, ref_language as c) ON  ((a.section_id=b.cd) and (a.language_id = c.cd)) WHERE year(a.fh_dt) = '2015' And region_id like 'B%' Order by fh_dt desc";
    MySqlDataAdapter daFt = new MySqlDataAdapter(listfh, conn);
    daFt.Fill(dtList);
```

the result return null. But when run the same command in Navicat Query, it return the correct answer (2 rows). What wrong ?

Comment: Do you have a way of capturing the query executed in Navicat and compare with the one you ran directly? I am not too sure about MySql but in Sql Server you can monitor the queries ran without too much fuzz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your connectionString(conn) was pointed your database properly and also mention your database name before your table/view name for to establish proper connection with the database objects like:

```
    string listfh = "Select class_id, location_nm, b.ref_desc, c.ref_desc ,a.days From DatabaseName.dbo.fh_info as a LEFT JOIN (DataBaseName.dbo.ref_section as b, DatabaseName.dbo.ref_language as c) ON  ((a.section_id=b.cd) and (a.language_id = c.cd)) WHERE year(a.fh_dt) = '2015' And region_id like 'B%' Order by fh_dt desc";
    MySqlDataAdapter daFt = new MySqlDataAdapter(listfh, conn);
    daFt.Fill(dtList);
```